Does the community have a right to know why a moderator was banned?
I was browsing the moderator elections and noticed one of the moderators from 2015 had a reputation of 1:

I can only assume that he was banned in August 2019 for 5 years, as I see his ban is expiring in 3 months, and his last post/answer was a few days before that date.
I don't expect to get the gossip or reasoning behind every single ban, but I also feel like it's relevant to the community when a past or current (at the time?) moderator is banned, and it wouldn't be crazy to put the reason on their profile, especially when we have a page listing our moderators.
Does the community have a right to know why moderators have been banned?

I mean, it would certainly be weird to edit something into someone else's profile, regardless of the circumstances

From my perspective, the most consistent answer would be "no". Community never has the right to know why any user is banned. That information has always been considered private between the user, the site moderation team, and (occasionally) the company. The only public facing information is the suspension banner on the user profile and even that is only visible for the duration of the suspension.

This really irks me to be honest. It is like you want to treat people who were moderators in the past like they're sex offenders. Based on a "feeling" too, there is no actual rationale here.

An ex-mod who is suspended has the same right to privacy about the circumstances as any other user who is suspended. Site policy is to not to engage in public shaming around suspensions, because once people have served their time, we want to welcome them back as contributors without disgrace and without grudges. This is a policy born of simple pragmatism; airing embarrassing specifics of someone's suspension-worthy misbehaviour generally just isn't useful, either for dealing with their individual cases or for setting policy about dealing with such misbehaviour. None of this policy calculus is inherently different if the suspended user is an ex-mod.
On the other hand, I think it's important we remember this policy of non-disclosure is a privacy right we choose to give to suspended users. The purpose is to protect them - not to protect the mod team or staff from scrutiny around how suspensions are used. If a suspended user themselves wants to discuss the circumstances of their suspension, or to explicitly waive their right to privacy around it and invite the mod team to publicly explain the suspension - perhaps because they think they have been done an injustice, or that there are important policy lessons to be learned from their case - then we should typically let them do that.
With this perspective in mind, and since I had some reasons I noted in (now deleted) comments to suspect that Jeremy might have been treated unfairly, I dropped him an email asking if there was anything he'd like me to post about his suspension. He indicated his embarrassment about how he had acted 5 years ago, and told me I was welcome to post this statement from him:

With distance from the events, and all things considered, I think the five years was reasonable and I am grateful that it wasn’t 500 years. While there were several individual incidents that I felt were unfair,  overall I made the situation a lot worse, and deeply regret how I acted. I didn’t leave the folks involved any real choice, and am sorry for contributing to a situation that was already difficult enough for them. I look forward to being able to resume contributing to the network (at least in small ways) in a few months. I don’t have any more details to share on the topic, and I promise that isn’t due to fear of legal consequences or anything like that.

That's that, then. If that's all he wishes to share, then, as with any other suspended user, that's all we have the right to know. And when his suspension ends later this year, we welcome him - a valuable past contributor who was around from the early days of Stack Overflow in 2008 until his suspension 5 years ago - back to the network, with his sins forgiven, to contribute again.

Again, someone takes initiative and actually communicates with direct positive results. Who does that? Calling people out on Twitter has replaced it long ago, you spoil a perfectly good opportunity to hold a cancellation party.

Thanks for giving such a mature answer Mark. I was thinking without empathy, which is ironically, perhaps how many people end up with a ban. I gotta watch out!

No.
Suspensions on the network are still designed as envisioned in 2009: A day in the penalty box.
And from the FAQ over on MSE, Why we don't keep public records of suspensions, it repeats:

At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. We don't hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back

Moderators are still users with real humans attached to them. I don't see why they all of a sudden have to be treated differently after they are de-modded and suspended for more than a year by SE staff. Adding any notice would just stir-up gossip for no reason.
We wait till August and see if the former mod returns to the network so they can demonstrate their behavior improved. It is up to users themselves whether they want to publicly discuss their suspension. There is a recent trend for high-profile users to come clean. Who knows what is in store for high-profile de-modded users.

The only case where this question would have any relevance, is if that moderator still was a moderator, even during the suspension.
Even then, the reason of the suspension isn't (and shouldn't be) public, but then a case could be made to question whether or not the moderator should stay "in office".
In this specific case, that user is no longer a moderator. I don't know when he was de-modded, or if the suspension had anything to do with that, but none of that really matters, to be honest.
He's just another user, now, sitting out a suspension.
None of our business.
